# Why does file extension matter: XML Parsing Error: not well-formed for plain text file

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I have a plain-text file in server. In order to load it into webpage i use the following code which i copied from the internet without fully understanding it:

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  }
  };
    xhttp.open("GET", "file", true);
    xhttp.send();
```

However, this generates a warning/error in firefox:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost/file
Line Number 1, Column 2:
```

If i change the file name to "file.txt" there is no error. So my question now: why does file extension matter?

Comment: You need to add the `doSomething` function as that is likely where the error lies

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius no, please ignore that, i changed to that because it is irrelevant to the question what i do with the file data. I edited the script tags out in order to hopefully be more clear (and more concise as a bonus)

Comment: you would not get an error relating to XML simply by sending an `XMLHttpRequest` to a text file. Nothing in the code you have shown, other than the `doSomething` function could be yielding that error  - so please add whatever code you have that is attempting to parse XML

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius this error shows to me even if `doSomething` does nothing (even if that line is removed).

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i'm sorry, apparently if the file extension of the file is `.txt` then the error does not occur. I didn't have this file extension and i just changed it when posting the question because i didn't thought that could cause the error. I will change my question to ask why file extension matters.

Comment: What matters is actually posting the code that is causing the problem, some sample data  and accurately describing the issue rather than use modified code which helps nobody

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thank you for the advice. I have edited the code to be minimal and tested that it still has the issue. (and found a way to fix it, which made my new question be about why changing file extension causes an error).

Comment: The file extension matters (in this instance) because it is an intrinsic part of the filename - you could have `file.jpg`, `file.png`, `file.txt` all in the same directory and this is perfectly valid yet you expect that piece of code to know which of these you are targeting in the request? Also - rather than concentrating on the old `XMLHttpRequest` you should probably take time to learn about the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thank you i was hoping to find a better alternative to XMLHttpRequest but i have hard time finding good resources on what i should learn. I would expect the file extension to be part of the filename and therefore if i target `file` it would mean a file without extension, if i wanted `file.txt` i would write `file.txt`, etc.